How to change the I2C configuration in ARM Trusted Firmware?
I have an STM32MP processor that needs ARM Trusted Firmware for communicating with the PMIC. But when I flashing the STM32MP processor with the firmware, I get an error that the I2C device is not ready.
The reason why the I2C device is not ready, is because it has the wrong pin configuration. The pin configuration is PZ4 and PZ5 for SDA and SCL. I need to change them to PF14 and PF15 inside the ARM Trusted Firmware before I compile. How can I achieve that?
The I2C device can be initilized, no problem there, but I get the error ERROR("I2C device not ready\n");.
ret = stm32_i2c_init(i2c, &i2c_init);
if (ret != 0) {
    ERROR("Cannot initialize I2C %x (%d)\n",
          i2c->i2c_base_addr, ret);
    panic();
}

if (!stm32_i2c_is_device_ready(i2c, pmic_i2c_addr, 1,
                   I2C_TIMEOUT_BUSY_MS)) {
    ERROR("I2C device not ready\n");
    panic();
}

Code from: ARM Trusted Hardware PMIC
The reference manual: STM32MP

The github repo with the trusted firmware has a whole GPIO section with appropriate GPIO config functions. Can't you use them to config the GPIO?

@Ilya Well, I found out that the Device Trees files must be used to change the GPIOS.
